# Reducing the dimensionality of a problem

Tags: regression, linear-model, regularization

My particular application needs me to build a linear model with a strong correlation structure amongst the independent variables. The dimensions of the problem are high, for instance 1million X 200. That is 1 million observations of 200 variables.

Since the problem is strongly collinear, I need to use some sort of regularization. I want to use non negative lasso ( due to the structure of the problem ). I am solving this in R and using the package penalized.

Now this is the problem I am running into, a calculation for the lambda1, the L-1 norm parameter using the optL1 function takes about 18 hours and counting. At this step I haven't even fitted for the final model. This is just the lambda1 evaluation step. This is just too long!

Unless I am missing something I need to shorten the time. One way to do it is to reduce the dimensionality of the problem. I am looking for some ideas to do that. The independent variables in my application have a relatively strong stable correlation structure. What will the implication if I just pick the topmost highly correlated variables and run the regression? Is there any other clever way to reduce the dimensionality of the problem?

Comment: How strong is a "relatively strong ... correlation structure"?  With one million observations, even correlations of 0.99 shouldn't be a problem, with the only caveat having to do with the condition number of the matrix $X^TX$.

Answer (score 4):

Lasso, as far as I know, is not a tool for dealing with collinearity issues, it is a tool for variable selection that penalizes the models based on their complexity.

There are a variety of methods of dealing with collinearity. If your individual variables are not vital, you can use partial least squares regression, which is something like principal component analysis, except that it also incorporates the relationship between the linear combination of the independent variables and the dependent variable.

If your individual variables are important, you can use ridge regression, which allows some bias in order to reduce the variance that is a problem with collinear models.

If there are particular pairs of variables that are very highly correlated, you can try just picking one, either based on substantive reasons or randomly. With 200 IVs, there are rather a lot of pairwise correlations to examine (if my arithmetic is right, it's 19,900) but it's not completely intractable.

Comment: Thanks for the note. I guess ideally I also want a sparse model, and the structure has me looking for only non negative beta, hence the choice of NNLASSO. So a little more detail around the problem is the follows.

Comment: The IV's are all grouped. There is 6 such groups. Within each group, the correlations are very strong. So there are approximately 35 odd variables per group. I was just thinking (maybe naively) to pick say the top 5 variables per group that have the highest correlation with the dependent var. And then use NNLASSO on the reduced problem.

Comment: Given that the IVs are grouped, I would suggest that you use principal component analysis to get one variable for each of the six groups, and then use those 6 variables in a regression. You would not then need NNLASSO, you could easily include all 6 variables (you could still use lasso if you wanted, but it wouldn't really be needed).

Comment: Thanks for the note, can you please elaborate more on that, I apologize I am a n00b to PCA. How do you combine all the variables to do a PCA? What about the correlation between the variables that belong to different groups, in others words there might be a need for regularization after PCA too?

Comment: Since you are using R you could look at the princomp function in the stats package. You would then, I think, use the scores from each of 6 runs of the function, then combine them into a data frame with your dependent variable and then run regression.

Comment: Ok, how about sparsity, I don't necessarily want a weight on all of the variables?

Comment: I don't understand. PCA will weight the variables to create a single variable out of each of the six sets.

Comment: I guess what I mean is that I dont want a weight on all of the variables when creating the PCA. In the worst case PCA will give some non zero weight to each of the 35 variables in the group. I want to do this due to other structural reasons of the problem.

Comment: Then I don't know what to suggest